# regular expression to find the repeating pattern +X+X+X

Tags: regex, limit

I have a regular expression

```
'^[0-9]*d[0-9]+(\+[0-9]*)*$'
```

to limit an input in the following format

```
str1 = '3d8+10'
str2 = 'd8+2+4'
```

However, the re I have also lets the string below through:

```
str3 = 'd8++2'
```

is there a way to write the regular expression in order to limit the pattern to
+X+X+X...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are looking for

```
'^[0-9]*d[0-9]+(\+[0-9]+)*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
^[0-9]*d[0-9]+(\+[0-9]+)*$
             a * here ^ allows only + to match as well
```

If the string must have at least one `+ n` then use `+` (one or more) at the end

```
^[0-9]*d[0-9]+(\+[0-9]+)+$
```